# Issue with sorting in a list of unequal size

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I am having a issue in sorting for in the given class,the data is not getting sorted,here both the list are of unequal size but list has keys present in list1 .FP is a bean class having key and value members .The data is not getting sorted.I want list1 in the same order has list appending extra keys at the end

```
public class MyList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FP f = new FP();
        f.setKey("s");
        f.setValue("he");
        FP f1 = new FP();
        f1.setKey("t");
        f1.setValue("she");
        List<FP> list = new ArrayList<FP>();
        list.add(f);
        list.add(f1);
        FP f2 = new FP();
        f2.setKey("t");
        f2.setValue("he");
        FP f3 = new FP();
        f3.setKey("s");
        f3.setValue("she");
        FP f4 = new FP();
        f4.setKey("u");
        f4.setValue("she");
        List<FP> list1 = new ArrayList<FP>();
        list1.add(f2);
        list1.add(f3);
        list1.add(f4);
        final Map<FP, Integer> indices = new HashMap<FP, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            indices.put(list.get(i), i);
        }
        Collections.sort(list1, new Comparator<FP>() {
            public int compare(FP o1, FP o2) {
                int index1 = (Integer) (indices.containsKey(o1) ? indices
                        .get(o1) : +1);
                int index2 = (Integer) (indices.containsKey(o2) ? indices
                        .get(o2) : +1);
                return index1 - index2;
            }

        });

        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("the data is" + list1.get(i).getKey());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess your issue is related to FP object didn't override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, because of that `(indices.containsKey(o1))` may return false.

When you use objects as content of collections and would like to do lookup using calls like `contains()` (or) `get(object)`, if you don't override `equals()` and `hashCode()` lookup may fail.

Example:

```
Set<FP> keySet=indices.keySet();
Iterator<FP> keySetIter = keySet.iterator();
while(keySetIter.hasNext())
{
FP fpObj = keySetIter.next();
//Write your equality condition here.
}
```

Comment: public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return super.equals(obj);
 }
 @Override
 public int hashCode() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return super.hashCode();
 }

Comment: but contains method gives me a error,please explian with my example

Comment: contains method? I am not seeing that in your code. Post error message.

Comment: i dont want to use equals and hashcode in my POJO class,how can i make the code working with contains method it is not working out for me

Comment: As i said, if you don't override equals() and hashcode() contains it not guaranteed to behave as expected. One way may be, loop the map everytime to check the object. But, that is costly.

Comment: What I am saying is Iterate the indices map keySet() and get object to find out whether object exists in map (or) not.

Comment: Added a small snippet to show how to iterate keySet. Hope that may give you some idea.

Comment: i am not able still solve my issue,please provide me the solution for my above snipper\t